# How to build chromedriver on a mac?

Tags: macos, build, selenium-chromedriver

I'm trying to build chromedriver from source for use in selenium

I can see the source here - https://cs.chromium.org/chromium/src/chrome/test/chromedriver/README.txt?sq=package:chromium

However, there doesn't seem to be any instructions for Mac on how to build it. For instance, does it require xcode? Is there any information on how to build it anywhere?

Answer (score 1):

https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/src/+/master/docs/mac_build_instructions.md

Chrome driver is a part of chromium project, Might be this link can help, just build the chromedriver target, instead of complete chromium.